# Does .nuxt/ files needs to be always committed?

Tags: nuxt.js

I wondered if this always needs to be committed and pushed.. These are files created by NuxtJS and if there are many developers working on the project. Conflicts may always occur. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: as suggested by @Md Mahamudul Hasan these files are auto generated and you don't need to put them on version control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.nuxt/ files are auto generated, so always you should avoid to committing this.

to avoid .nuxt/ folder commit, just add **.nuxt** into **.gitigonore** file

Comment: Wow! Thanks! I just find it weird that this is not included on the automated `.gitignore` of nuxt